# Firebase authenticaiton error handling in unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, asynchronous, error-handling, firebase-authentication

I have been struggling to find a solution for this and it seems that i'm doing something in the wrong way due to my limited knowladge, so here is the breakdown of the problem:

```
public void RegisterNewUser()
{        
    FetchRegisterInputValues();        
    if (CheckRegisterDataIntegrity())
    {
        _auth.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(_email, _password).ContinueWith(task => {
            if (task.IsCanceled) {
                Debug.LogError("CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync was canceled.");
                return;
            }
            if (task.IsFaulted)
            {
                HandleRegistrationErrors(task.Exception);              
                return;
            }                                
            // Firebase user has been created.
            Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser newUser = task.Result;
            Debug.LogFormat("Firebase user created successfully: {0} ({1})",
                newUser.DisplayName, newUser.UserId);
        });
    }
    else if (!CheckRegisterDataIntegrity())
    {
        HandleRegistrationErrors(new AggregateException("passwords do not match"));
    }
}
```

above is the Registration function that I got straight from Firebase docs, it's very straightforward
the `FetchRegisterInputValues();` function gets the email and passwords, the `CheckRegisterDataIntegrity()` compares the password with the password conformation in the form, and finally `HandleRegistrationErrors(task.Exception);` is meant to fire a popup panel to show the error,

this is how `HandleRegistrationErrors(task.Exception);` looks

```
private void HandleRegistrationErrors(AggregateException errMsg)
{       
    print("its here from the errors method " + errMsg.Message);
    registerErrorPopup.OpenNotification();
    registerErrorPopup.description = errMsg.Message;
}
```

it's using a UI asset from the asset store, the `.OpenNotification();` starts the animation and pops it up, and then im just showing the message.

**Now, I got two problems**, the first is when there is an error encountered by Firebase and the `if (task.IsFaulted)` Condition is true, the `HandleRegistrationErrors` function should be called, right?. well that's exactly what happens, except only the `print("it's here from the errors method " + errMsg.Message);` line gets called and the rest of the function does not execute, I thought at first that its a problem with asset, but I tried doing it manually (created a native UI with unity and used SetActive() method to start the popUp), but again only print method executed, I think its because of the 
 `CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync` is Asynchronous and I should handle errors accordingly, but I really don't know how to go about it and there is no documentation that I could find.
**The second problem** is how to get the correct Error Message because of the `task.Exception.Message` always returns me a "One or more errors occurred". while the `task.Exception` itself gives the right message but it's not formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first question is the easiest. To update your code with the minimal amount of effort, just replace `ContinueWith` with `ContinueWithOnMainThread` will force logic onto the main thread. Also, you should avoid calling `task.Result` if `task.Exception` is non-null as it will just raise the exception (see the [related documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8)).

For the threading related stuff: I go into much more detail about threading with Firebase and Unity [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/07/firebase-and-tasks-how-to-deal-with.html) and you can read about the `ContinueWithOnMainThread` extension [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/extensions/task-extension).

For your second issue, the issue you're running into is that `task.Exception` is an [AggregateException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception?view=netframework-4.8). I typically just attach a debugger and inspect this when debugging (or [let Crashlytics analyze it](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/crashlytics-and-unity-part-1-ca0598862918?source=friends_link&sk=d8dc15756699abf2b18bd2b7160c469b) in the field), and my UI state is only concerned about success or failure. If you want to inspect the error, the documentation I linked for `AggregateException` recommends doing something like:

```
task.Exception.Handle((e) => Debug.LogError($"Failed because {e}"));
```

Although I would play with `.Flatten()` or `.GetBaseException()` to see if those are easier to deal with.

I hope this helps!

--Patrick

Comment: You are a true lifesaver, I watched your youtube videos to get started and you helped me here as well, thank you so much. The ContinueWithOnMainThread method made the UI work as intended, and I used .GetBaseException().Message to get the right Error message, it's all working FINE.